# Trying to read a serial number into a variable to compare to a list of serial numbers to rename a machine

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to rename thin clients to a given Asset Tag associated with the serial number from the BIOS of said thin client.

I've been trying to research how to do this but I am coming up with fragments with no clear idea of how to tie it all together.  I know how to get the Serial number from the Thin Client into a variable, but getting the text file into a variable for processing has eluded me.

The idea is...

Get the serial from the thin client into $serialNum (ie. SN283973)

Load the text file containing the serial number and the assigned Asset Tag into $fileArray (ie: SN283973, P8003947)

Look for $serialNum in $fileArray and put the associated Asset Tag into $assetTag (ie. P8003947)

From there I can use the vendor specific code to apply the $assetTag to the BIOS file and upload it to the device to apply the change.

I'm not necessarily looking for someone to write this for me, if someone can give me some pointers so that I can go research the problem using the right terminology that would be great.

I want to learn how to fish, I just need pointed to the lake.

Serial number / asset tag file:

```
Hostname    Deployed
8CN84YR P807086A
8CN84ZV P807023B
8CN84ZX P807029C
8CN840Y P801056D
8CN8416 P801029E
```

Comment: Here is the start of my code, still trying to figure the compare out.


serialNum="$(dmidecode -s chassis-asset-tag)"

mapfile -t aTags < /tmp/Asset_Tags.txt

[[ -n "${aTags[$serialNum]}" ]] && printf '%s is in array\n' "$aTags"

Comment: Not sure if I got it right: is that text file a simple mapping between serial number and asset tag? In that case, why don't you lookup that asset tag directly using grep?

Comment: Please add example content from your "text file" to the question.

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it or the errors you encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm amazed this question has received so many upvotes...

Comment: The asset Tag is an arbitrary number assigned in the real world.  The Thin Client has not idea what that Asset tag is.  I can get the Serial number from the device using some scripting, so I need to use the SN from the TC find the Asset Tag from my file.  My hope is that once I have the script working that I can place the code in the Device manager software and let it push the job to the TC's and let them figure out what their Asset Tag is and apply it en-mass rather than me doing them individually.

Comment: Hostname Deployed  <br/>
8CN84YR P807086A  <br/>
8CN84ZV P807023B  <br/>
8CN84ZX P807029C  <br/>
8CN840Y P801056D  <br/>
8CN8416         P801029E  <br/>

Comment: Tried to format it sorry.

Comment: As each line consists of a serial number and asset tag, you can get the asset tag as follows: serialNum=$(dmidecode -s chassis-asset-tag); assetTag=$(grep $serialNum <YOUR_FILE> | awk '{print $2}')

Comment: @phaebel - you can replace your grep/awk with [just awk](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: @phaebel  So, I took your sample and manually ran it through on the terminal and it seemed to work.  However, now when I run it through the Device manager I get both the Serial Number and Asset Tag for the $ASSET_TAG Variable.  When I look through the log for my echo I see that there is a "\r" between the two columns.  Should I not be using a Tab delimited file?  would CSV be better?

Comment: @Tanktalus  I read your link and tired it, but something blew up and the code didn't work at all for grabbing data from the file to compare the serial to.  I am obviously missing something.    Sorry, I am very new to Bash scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the serial number in `$serial`:

```
assetTag=$(awk -e '$1 == "'"$serial"'"{print $2; q}' <YOUR_FILE>)
```

The absurd amount of quotes is to get `$1` and `$2` into single quotes so the `$` sigils are kept and `awk` sees them, but to get `$serial` to be interpreted by the shell, and its value to appear to `awk` inside quotes.  Could be done with fewer quotes but more `\` escapes.

This doesn't use a regex, but uses an exact match for your serial number in the first column, which means that if your serial number is a partial match for any other record, it won't be considered a match here, only an exact match on the field will work. The `q` tells awk to quit after finding and printing the matched row's second column.

Comment: I think `-e` is specific to `gawk` and I wonder why you use it at all? Are you sure `q` causes exit?

Comment: @tanktalus  Thanks!  It pulls the Asset tag out of the table and puts it where I need it.  Also thank you for explaining it, I still need to wrap my brain around it but at least I now have a staring point thanks to you.  Cheers!